# How can I know how many parameter in rocksdb

Tags: rocksdb

I already read the rocksdb overview, but i can't find "how many parameters used in rocksdb"
where can I find that?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any explicit count on how many rocksdb options are used. You can check table.h, options.h, advanced_options.h to find out about the options.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).